# How to integrate Svelte in other App Stack

Tags: backend, svelte, svelte-3

I would like to know if it's possible to integrate Svelte for the front app with a different backend stack than the default one, with a python, Ruby on Rails or PHP server for instance?

Is it possible to use it for a multi-pages app, or should it be used only for single page apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you can render html tags with any backend.

```html
<div id="svelte-app"></div>
<script src="dist/main.js"></script>
```

This kind of setup is useful if most of the page is server rendered but you'll want to add some interactive components to a page.

```js
// src/main.js
import App from './App.svelte';

new App({
  target: document.getElementById('svelte-app'),
  props: {
    name: 'world',
  },
});
```

But you'll need something that performs the Svelte compilation step.

You could use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) for that:

```sh
npm install --save-dev vite svelte @sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte
```

```js
// vite.config.js
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      formats: ["es"],
      fileName: (format)=>`main.js`,
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/main.js"),
    },
  },
});
```

Running `npx vite build --watch` will generate the dist/main.js and recompile on code changes.

Alternatively use [rollup-plugin-svelte](https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte) or [svelte-loader](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-loader) if you are already using a bundler.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in integrating Svelte with different backends than there would be with any other frontend technology.

For multipage apps, I recommend using [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs). In this case, there is a special `fetch` HTTP hook that helps integrations on the server-side rendering and it is recommended all backend APIs are exposed as REST/JSON to have the best support for the `fetch` SSR handling.

[Read my blog post about how I integrated Svelte with Python backend](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/building-cryptocurrency-website). [You can find the actual frontend source code here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/).